# Class best practice - Methods with no parameters vs attribute overwriting itself

Tags: python

Apologizes for the clunky title.  But I was wondering what the best practice was for the below example in terms of TDD and maintainability.

Take the class below.

```
class sampleClass():

    def __init__(self, datframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.other_dataframe = pandas.load_csv(....)

    def modify_dataframe_method1(self):
        self.dataframe = self.dataframe.join(self.other_dataframe)

    def modify_dataframe_method2(self, df):
        df = df.join(self.other_dataframe)
        return df
```

Both of those methods can do the same thing, with just different syntax.  If I created another method within the class, either of these statements would work end in the same result for self.dataframe.

```
def process(self):
    self.modify_dataframe_method1()

def process(self):
    self.dataframe = self.modify_dataframe_method2(self.dataframe)
```

Why are the pros and cons of each approach.  While I am using a dataframe in the example, I can imagine doing similar things to jsons or other data structures.

Comment: They don't do the same thing at all; one modifies the instance of `sampleClass`, the other doesn't. Discussing when each is useful or not is far too broad a topic.

Comment: So, I guess I am missing something and maybe thats the heart of the question.  Dont they both modify the dataframe attribute of the `sampleClass`?  One of them does it by overwriting it within a method while the other does it using a parameter and returning the result.

Comment: No, `modify_dataframe_method2` modifies the dataframe passed as an argument, leaving `self.other_dataframe` untouched.